# Whatsapp Cloud API The parameter messaging_product is required

Tags: php, whatsapp

I'm trying to add WhatsApp Cloud API to our CRM but can't get it to work properly. Testing with sending a message I get the following error:

> Array ( [error] => Array ( [message] => (#100) The parameter
> messaging_product is required. [type] => OAuthException [code] => 100
> [fbtrace_id] => AE0w_gLBZGvIf00W-p7ctfv ) )

Everything seems to work fine through Postman but only sending message with template. I tested both on my server but keep getting the same error.

Here is my code:

```
$text_arr = array(
        'preview_url' => 'false', 
        'body' => 'Hello, this is a test from home'
    );

    $fields = array(
        'messaging_product' => 'whatsapp',
        'recipient_type' => 'individual',
        'to' => '18292605656',
        'type' => 'text',
        'text' => $text_arr
    );


    $header = array(
        'Authorization: Bearer ' => $token,
        'Content-Type' => "application/json"
    );

    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields) );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    $response = json_decode(curl_exec($curl), true);
    print_r($response);
    
    $status_code = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
           
    curl_close($curl);
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this API, but the 2nd `$fields = array(` in your code overrides the 1st

Comment: That was a typo, but either way I encountered the same error. REMOVED that typo from the post.

Comment: @Wilson do you have solution for your case above ? because I have similar case but don't have solution...

Comment: @M.SyamsulArifin you can try Ricardo Martìnez Martìnez's answer (headers must not have key and value), it's worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I my case, i had comments('//') in my body json objet. I just removed it.
ie. I had this:

```
{
 "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
 "recipient_type": "individual",
 "to": "{{Recipient-Phone-Number}}",
 "type": "text",
 "text": {// the text object
     "preview_url": false,
     "body": "Bonjour, votre code de vérification est: 123678."
  }
}
```

And I jsut remove commands (//) from json body:

```
{
     "messaging_product": "whatsapp",
     "recipient_type": "individual",
     "to": "{{Recipient-Phone-Number}}",
     "type": "text",
     "text": {
         "preview_url": false,
         "body": "Bonjour, votre code de vérification est: 123678."
      }
    }
```

After that, all work well. I think it can help somebody!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error, headers must not have key and value.

$headers = array(
"Authorization: Bearer ACCES_TOKEN",
"Content-Type: application/json",
);